# Configure Postgres application users with Terraform for RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, rds, terraform

[Terraform allows you](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html) to define Postgres master user and password with the options `username` and `password`. But there is no option to set up an application postgres user, how would you do that?

Answer (score 17):

The [AWS RDS resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html) is only used for creating/updating/deleting the RDS resource itself using the AWS APIs.

To create users or databases on the RDS instance itself you'd either want to use another tool (such as [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html) - the official command line tool or a configuration management tool such as [Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/postgresql_user_module.html)) or use Terraform's [Postgresql provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/postgresql/index.html).

Assuming you've already created your RDS instance you would then connect to the instance as the master user and then create the application user with something like this:

```
provider "postgresql" {
  host = "postgres_server_ip1"
  username = "postgres_user"
  password = "postgres_password"
}

resource "postgresql_role" "application_role" {
  name = "application"
  login = true
  password = "application-password"
  encrypted = true
}
```

Comment: This is not "Terraform's Postgresql provider". It is *a* Terraform Postgresql provider. It is not provided by Hashicorp.

Answer (score 4):

addition to @ydaetskcoR answer, here is the full example for RDS PostgreSQL;

```
provider "postgresql" {
  scheme    = "awspostgres"
  host      = "db.domain.name"
  port      = "5432"
  username  = "db_username"
  password  = "db_password"
  superuser = false
}


resource "postgresql_role" "new_db_role" {
    name                = "new_db_role"
    login               = true
    password            = "db_password"
    encrypted_password  = true
}

resource "postgresql_database" "new_db" {
  name              = "new_db"
  owner             = postgresql_role.new_db_role.name
  template          = "template0"
  lc_collate        = "C"
  connection_limit  = -1
  allow_connections = true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The above two answers requires the host that runs the terraform has direct access to the RDS database, and usually you do not. I propose to code what you need to do in a lambda function (optionally with secrets manager for retrieving the master password):

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "terraform_lambda_func" {
  filename      = "${path.module}/lambda_function/lambda_function.zip"
  ...
}
```

and then use the following data source (example) to call the lambda function.

```
data "aws_lambda_invocation" "create_app_user" {
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.terraform_lambda_func.function_name
  
  input = <<-JSON
    {
      "step": "create_app_user"
    }
  JSON
    
  depends_on = [aws_lambda_function.terraform_lambda_func]
  provider = aws.primary
}
```

This solution id generic. It can do what a lambda function can do with AWS API can do, which is basically limitless.

Comment: This is clever. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72261589/terraform-data-source-to-execute-only-on-dependency-change